# Is there a way to merge two iterators into the same Vec?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have two iterators that will end up merging into the same `Vec`, but I need to perform a filter on the end result before merging. For example:

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4].into_iter().map(|x| x * 2);
let b = vec![0, 3, 5, 6, 7].into_iter().map(|x| x * 3);
let c = a + b;
assert_eq!(
    c.filter(|&x| x > 5).collect::<Vec<u8>>(),
    vec![6, 8, 9, 15, 18, 21]
);
```

I *could* do something like this:

```
let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4]
    .into_iter()
    .map(|x| x * 2)
    .collect::<Vec<u8>>();
let b = vec![0, 3, 5, 6, 7]
    .into_iter()
    .map(|x| x * 3)
    .collect::<Vec<u8>>();
a.extend(b);
assert_eq!(
    a.into_iter().filter(|&x| x > 5).collect::<Vec<u8>>(),
    vec![6, 8, 9, 15, 18, 21]
);
```

But the extra allocation kills performance in my case (yes, I checked!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for [`Iterator::chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain)

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4].into_iter().map(|x| x * 2);
let b = vec![0, 3, 5, 6, 7].into_iter().map(|x| x * 3);
let c = a.chain(b);
assert_eq!(
    c.filter(|&x| x > 5).collect::<Vec<u8>>(),
    vec![6, 8, 9, 15, 18, 21]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [`extend()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend):

```rust
let a = (0..500000).map(|x| x * 2);
let b = (0..500000).map(|x| x * 3);
let mut c = Vec::with_capacity(a.size_hint().1.unwrap() + b.size_hint().1.unwrap());
c.extend(a);
c.extend(b);
```

This requires you to explicitly use `with_capacity()` which `chain()` and `collect()` would have done for you. In the situation where `a` is already constructed, `extend()` will be suitable instead of building a temporary vector.

I did not find any benchmark difference between `chain()` and `extend` in this case ([benchmark](https://gist.github.com/c8fcb2cb741f28b84ba8c1a3876ed5e1))

> This doesn't do the filtering. [Sebastian Redl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8922/sebastian-redl)

Correct! Fixing this mistake shows that for some reason, LLVM no longer optimizes `chain()` now. The version with `extend`:

```rust
let a = (0..500000).map(|x| x * 2);
let b = (0..500000).map(|x| x * 3);
let mut c = Vec::with_capacity(a.size_hint().1.unwrap() + b.size_hint().1.unwrap());
c.extend(a.filter(|&x| x > 5));
c.extend(b.filter(|&x| x > 5));
```

Is twice as fast than the version with `chain` (this is what I expected in the first place):

```rust
let a = (0..500000).map(|x| x * 2);
let b = (0..500000).map(|x| x * 3);
let _c: Vec<_> = a.chain(b).filter(|&x| x > 5).collect();
```

([benchmark](https://gist.github.com/449d6f4c5b8932995e9bc8c60e15b1f9))

Comment: This doesn't do the filtering.